# JasperServer 5.5, AdHoc view date display issue

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

After creating an AdHoc view with JasperServer 5.5, I cannot use one of the date type fields for display.  Using this field in a crosstab give a generic error in the UI and generates the following error in the server log:

```
2014-06-06 12:33:56,437 ERROR AdhocAjaxController,http-bio-80-exec-3:888 - ad hoc controller exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'n'
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:845)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.applyPattern(SimpleDateFormat.java:2199)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.DefaultFormatFactory.createDateFormat(DefaultFormatFactory.java:127)
at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.service.AdhocEngineServiceImpl.formatValue(AdhocEngineServiceImpl.java:1903)
<...>
```

Where in JasperReports server would the date format be specified for this specific field of this specific AdHoc view and why would it contain an "Illegal pattern character 'n'" if it was created through the UI?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you edit the display properties of date column in domain then you get this error or when you drag the date column in ad hoc view gets error "Couldn't process previous request". This is a known bug.
2. To resolve this issue you will need to export domain schema file and find the attribute "defaultMask=null" for the date field you are getting this error. Remove this attribute "defaultMask=null" and import this schema.xml file again.
3. You will not get this error again until you edit the display properties of date field.
4. I also observed that this error is getting when you are working on report/ad hoc view after their domain is updated. Try to prefer building new ad hoc view if you have done too many changes to domain and you get this error.